# prisma nested query with type

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I am trying to query a listing based on location(country) and a bunch of other parameters. The country name will be passed in and return the listing located in that country
Here is the schema:

```
type Location {
  city String
  state String
  country String
}
type PropertyLocation {
  address String
  location Location
  latlng Float[]
}
model Listing {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title String
  description String
  imageSrc String
  detailImage String[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  dateModified DateTime @default(now())
  category String
  roomCount Int
  bathroomCount Int
  guestCount Int
  location PropertyLocation
  userId String @db.ObjectId
  price Int
  review Float
  isActive Boolean @default(true)
  
  reservations Reservation[]
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

Here is the query:

```
    if (locationValue)
    query.location = {
      location: {
        country: locationValue,
      },
    };

    const listings = await dbClient.listing.findMany({
      where: query,
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: "desc",
      },
    });
```

However, I am getting this error I can't figure out:

```
Unknown arg `location` in where.location.location for type PropertyLocationCompositeFilter. Available args:

type PropertyLocationCompositeFilter {
  equals?: PropertyLocationObjectEqualityInput
  is?: PropertyLocationWhereInput
  isNot?: PropertyLocationWhereInput
}
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am having a similar issue now..

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue until I came across `composite types` on their [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/special-fields-and-types/composite-types).

So basically, for embedded objects with prisma, you're supposed to use `is`, `equals`, `isNot`, and `isSet` for it to work.

- `is` - Use this if you want to query with optional fields.
- `equals` - When using this, you should specify the whole object fields.
- `isNot` - Filter results by non-matching composite types.
- `isSet` - Filter optional fields to include only results that have been set.

So in your example, you'd do as follows

```
if (locationValue)
  query = {
   ...query,
   location: {
     is: {
       country: locationValue,
     }
   }
  }

const listings = await dbClient.listing.findMany({
  where: query,
  orderBy: {
    createdAt: "desc",
  },
});
```